# Collection object with a foreach

Tags: laravel

i try to run a query who display the licences from the structures who are in relation with the Auth::user()->structure

but i get only the licences from the last "structure" in the collection , i would like all the licences from the $structures collection ..

someone have an idea ? maybe i'm wrong with the query ..

```
here my controller : 

    public function licenceToValid(){

            // here i grab the collection of the clubs who are in relation with my "comite " **(Comite have many clubs)** 
            $structures = Structure::where(['structure_pere_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])->get();


            foreach ($structures as $structure) {

                //here the query to display the licences from the structures 
                $licences = Licencies::where('structure_id' , $structure->id)->get();

            }

            return view('licencie/valider' , compact('licencies'));


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `whereIn` which would solve your problem and be much more efficient (1 query is better than many queries).

```
$structures = Structure::where(['structure_pere_id' => Auth::user()->structure->id])->get();

$licences = Licencies::whereIn('structure_id', $structures->pluck('id'))->get();

return view('licencie/valider' , compact('licencies'));
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!! i didn't had the idea to try the pluck method for the id !!! thanks so much for your help ..... i wish you a good day